# Python, cast Integer to bytes.

Tags: python-3.x, arrays, blowfish

i am newbie in python, and cannot do some easy stuf.
I have a code from java

```
raw[j] = (byte) (chksum & 0xff)
raw[j + 1] = (byte) (chksum >> 0x08 & 0xff)
raw[j + 2] = (byte) (chksum >> 0x10 & 0xff)
raw[j + 3] = (byte) (chksum >> 0x18 & 0xff)
```

Where raw is a array of bytes
I need to do it in python. But how can i cast int to bytes?
And maybe anybody knows where can i get the library for using Blowfish crypting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `struct` module to cast to and from bytes.

Your example would be:

```
raw[j] = struct.pack("B", chksum & 0xff)
etc..
```

Reference: http://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html